# Where to put HttpClient request and response converter functions

Tags: angular, typescript

In our angular application we are converting every api request and response types to our app specific type so it is easier to implement a property change in a big application.

At the moment we are doing that directly in the Service with a `map` on the `HttpClient` observable. But this is a little bit cumbersome, especially for requests that return the same entity (e.g. `get` and `post` both returning an entity).

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('/path/to/todos').pipe(
      map((res: any) => res.map((item) => ({
        id: res.id,
        name: res.specialProperty
      })))
    );
  }

  public getTodoById(id: string): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('/path/to/todos/' + id).pipe(
      map((res: any) => ({
        id: res.id,
        name: res.specialProperty
      }))
    );
  }
}
```

Now I have found a cool article describing the Implementation of an adapter to keep your code more DRY. See. https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/09/consuming-apis-in-angular-the-model-adapter-pattern/

My Problem with that approach is that for a big backend service we have to create a lot of AdapterClasses, where maybe a module with a couple of exported functions would do the trick.

Now my question: Do you have any experience with adapting requests and responses in an Angular Application on a large scale and where do you keep your "mapping" functions?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, this `adapter` approach is just a fancy factory method. As you said. This can easily be achieved by using a "dumb" function that takes a given set of data and maps it to whatever object you want (essentially what the adapter does). We split our app in 3 levels. `Component <-> "data"Service <-> GatewayService`. `"data"Service` is domain-driven. The gateway implements the actual call to the backend (and was generated from JSON schema). The `dataService` mapped the requests/responses accordingly and populated it further.

Comment: We do it exactly the same way but we do the mapping already in the GatewayService. My Thinking was where to put these dumb functions. At the moment we use private functions, but then the unit testing can not be done in an isolated manner.

Comment: I disagree Pascal. You can very well unit test each gateway function. You mock the HttpResponse and expect a certain outcome (interface/class) that needs to be fulfilled :) - That way changes in either the mocked response or build-method would result in a failed test.

Comment: Yes of course, but at the same time I always also have an `httpTestingController.expectOne()` as an additional expect block and I really wanted to keep testing of the mapping and testing of the REST implementation separated. But maybe this is a little bit too excessive. I just really like the idea of testing these pure functions in isolation.

Comment: Nothing stops you from moving these files in a separate `model.ts` file which holds the interface along with a possible `build` method ;)

Comment: Yes true but then again an argument could be made that the mapping method belongs in the `GatewayService` to honour the principle of separation of concerns as the mapping input (response from the API) should only be known to the method that calls the backend and probably not be exported either as we do want our app to only work with its own model everywhere else. You can see why I am a little bit indecisive as everything has its own pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could have a bunch of model classes, and theoreticaly you can then map response to a class, depending on your custom logic.

as an example you could have classes like these:

```
export class Model1 {
  static type = 'model1';
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ...;
}
```

response from backend example:

```
{
  size: 1,
  itemType: 'model1',
  items: [{name: 'abc', id: 1}]
}
```

and interceptor logic which will map items to corresponding models

```
mapResponse(response: MyTypicalResponce) {
  const model = allModels.find(({type}) => type == response.itemType);
  return {
     ...response,
     items: model ? response.items.map(item => new Model(item)) : response.items;
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks way too complex

Comment: maybe, but no additional code would be required to map these models. every time you are using angular http, models will be already wrapped in classes

Comment: Like @BojanKogoj said, this is a little bit complicated. I do not have a problem with using pure functions, I even prefer it. It is more a scaffolding question for where to put these functions.

Comment: That's not the only problem. This way you can't nest these functions, which is an important part if you have nested objects in response.